# sap.m.Select with ListItems using colored icons

Tags: sapui5

I would like to use a `sap.m.Select` control which shows a list of `sap.ui.core.ListItem` controls with an icon. This works out of the box, all select items with their icons are rendered in their default blueish color.

However, based on a property in the bound model, I would like to have the icon in a certain color. To style a control conditionally, I would use the `customData` aggregation, and based on the mapped key-value, I would render the accompanying style. For other use cases (lists, tables, etc) this works like a charm.

The issue is -- I think -- with the `sap.ui.core.ListItem` control. If I use the following, simplified example:

```
<Select selectedKey="{/mykey}">
    <core:ListItem key="1" text="One" icon="sap-icon://circle-task-2">
        <core:customData>
            <core:CustomData
                key="iconcolor"
                value="grey"
                writeToDom="true"/>
        </core:customData>
    </core:ListItem>
</Select>
```

...then I would expect a `data-iconcolor` attribute being written to the list item (because of the `writeToDom="true"` property being set). However, nothing is rendered, and as such I cannot create a CSS selector based on that data property.

Does anyone have an idea on how to render a Select control with colored icons? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:**

Based on the solution provided by @MrNajzs below, it turned out my prototype did not work because I did not use databinding... good to know :-)

I also had to render the currently selected item in the drowpdown, but that is basically the same approach

For those interested, here's the complete running example:

```js
sap.ui.controller("view1.initial", {
    onInit : function() {
        const oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
            listitems: [
                {
                    "status": "none",
                    "desc": "None"
                },
                {
                    "status": "inprogress",
                    "desc": "In progress"
                },
                {
                    "status": "done",
                    "desc": "Done"
                }
            ],
            selectedKey: "none"
        });

        this.getView().setModel(oModel);
    }
});

sap.ui.xmlview("main", {
    viewContent: jQuery("#view1").html()
})
.placeAt("uiArea");
```

```css
[data-iconcolor="none"] span.sapMSelectListItemIcon {
    color: grey;
}

[data-iconcolor="inprogress"] span.sapMSelectListItemIcon {
    color: blue;
}

[data-iconcolor="done"] span.sapMSelectListItemIcon {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
    src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
    data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
    data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"
    data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"></script>

<div id="uiArea"></div>

<script id="view1" type="ui5/xmlview">
    <mvc:View 
      controllerName="view1.initial"
      xmlns="sap.m"
      xmlns:u="sap.ui.unified"
      xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
      xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
        <Select
            forceSelection="true"
            selectedKey="{/selectedKey}"
            items="{/listitems}">
            <core:ListItem key="{status}" text="{desc}" icon="sap-icon://circle-task-2">
                <core:customData>
                    <core:CustomData
                      key="iconcolor"
                      value="{status}"
                      writeToDom="true"/>
                </core:customData>
            </core:ListItem>
            <customData>
                <core:CustomData
                  key="iconcolor"
                  value="{/selectedKey}"
                  writeToDom="true"/>
            </customData>
        </Select>
    </mvc:View>
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey this work's for me.

Model-Controller.js

```
var oItems = new JSONModel({
                items: [{
                    "key": "01",
                    "text": "01",
                    "color": "yellow",
                    "icon": "sap-icon://save"
                }, {
                    "key": "02",
                    "text": "02",
                    "color": "green",
                    "icon": "sap-icon://cancel"
                }]
            });
            this.setModel(oItems, "select");
```

Select-View.xml

```
    <Select forceSelection="false" width="300px" items="{ path: 'select>/items'}">
            <core:ListItem key="{select>key}" text="{select>text}" icon="{select>icon}">
                <core:customData>
                    <core:CustomData key="iconcolor" value="{select>color}" writeToDom="true"/>
                </core:customData>
            </core:ListItem>
        </Select>
```

style.css

```
[data-iconcolor="green"] {
    color: green;
}

[data-iconcolor="yellow"] {
    color: yellow;
}
```

Result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works! For speed reasons, I prototyped an example without databinding and that somehow did not work. With databinding, the `data-` property is written to the DOM. Thanks a million